# CSS keeps reseting when run in localhost

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue with my website I am creating. I have at least 4 external CSS files which control different HTML files. The issue I am having is that whenever I run my HTML files in localhost the CSS is being reset which is quite bothering. So how do I prevent it from being reset?

CSS-sample of what I am trying to change

```
.container {
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  height: 1150px;
}
```

Full sample

[Code](https://codepen.io/jerrome-ching/pen/OKXpzz)

[image: problem]

Comment: What you meant by resetting?

Comment: Poor explanation of problem. My guess is you are talking about navigating away from the page and back?

Comment: Please kindly help to edit. thank you

Comment: This happens because bootstrap also implements a css class with the same name `container`. You can either use change your classname (container-custom) a bit to avoid name collision. Generally.. using !important is not a good practice.

Comment: ty  sir didn't think about that

Comment: but is there such a class as container custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to override some styles use the `!important` keyword

```
   .container {
      background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233) !important;
      height: 1150px !important;
    }
```

For more information about this, please refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: [!important should only be used as an absolute last ditch method](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#never) . You really should try and use [speceficity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to solve this